# Altium Database and Footprint density

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-assembly, footprint

I am currently trying to use the database in Altium, but I have one big question:

I was expecting to get one database entry per resistor value. But, for a single 100k 0805 resistor (for example), there are three footprint choices, by density:

- IPC High Density
- IPC Medium Density
- IPC Low Density

Why three choices for the footprint? How do I choose?

Comment: Just select the "low density" (largest footprint) variant if you have no tight space requirements.

Answer (score 6):

The IPC Density setting has to do with how tightly-packed with components your design will be.  In Altium (and other software) this will affect both the land patterns and also the clearances.

For example, "high density" is to be used if you need to place components very close to each other.  A high-density footprint will have smaller soldering locations and also will allow parts to placed closer together without raising any errors.

I would recommend low-density unless you run out of room.  The primary reason is for ease-of-soldering.  The low-density pads are generally large enough to solder to by hand, whereas the high-density pads can require reflow soldering.

Also, some assembly houses charge a premium for tightly-packed component placement.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand a question correctly, maybe this could help. Regarding to component density on your board (layout) there are some small changes in the footprint size (not only pads but also overlay and mask expansion for example).

Check IPC-7351

Answer (score 0):

From the IPC-7351 (Generic Requirements for Surface Mount Design and Land Pattern Standard) section 3.1.5.4:

``The suffix letters L, M, and N have been reserved to signify when the land protrusion is at their minimum (least), maximum (most), or median (nominal) protrusion or use environment as follows:

- M – Maximum (Most) Material Condition (Density Level A)
- N – Median (Nominal) Material Condition (Density Level B)
- L – Minimum (Least) Material Condition (Density Level C''

From Tables 3-2 to 3-14 in the same standard, choosing M, N, or L sets the dimensions of the copper pads and the courtyard excess (minimum electrical and mechanical clearance around the component). If you average over the tables, you find that two L components can be packed as close as 0.2 mm (4 thou) apart, N components as close as 0.5 mm (20 thou) apart, and M components as close as 1 mm (39 thou) apart.

We've found that most fabrication and assembly houses can handle N land patterns. Expect to pay more for assembly using L land patterns (you need a pick and place machine, laser cut stencils, ...).

If you are hand soldering, M is easy to do, and N isn't too bad. M and N aren't bad to rework. If you are using L land patterns to increase component density,  it's hard to get an iron between components.